# How to render text on image with RMagick and Word wrap?

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I need to render some text (unicode, helvetica, white, 22px, bold) on a image (1024x768).

This is my code so far:

```
img = Magick::ImageList.new("my_bg_img.jpg")
txt = Magick::Draw.new

img.annotate(txt, 800, 600, 0, 0, "my super long text that needs to be auto line breaked and cropped") {
      txt.gravity = Magick::NorthGravity
      txt.pointsize = 22
      txt.fill = "#ffffff"
      txt.font_family = 'helvetica'
      txt.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
}

img.format = "jpeg"

return img.to_blob
```

Its all fine but its not automatically breaking the lines (Word wrap) to fit all the text into my defined area ( 800x600 ).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On the Draw.annotate method the width parameter doesn't seem to have an effect on the rendering text.

I have faced the same problem and I developed this functions to fit the text to a specified width by adding new lines.

I have a function to check if a text fit a specified width when drawed on image

```
def text_fit?(text, width)
  tmp_image = Image.new(width, 500)
  drawing = Draw.new
  drawing.annotate(tmp_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, text) { |txt|
    txt.gravity = Magick::NorthGravity
    txt.pointsize = 22
    txt.fill = "#ffffff"
    txt.font_family = 'helvetica'
    txt.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
  }
  metrics = drawing.get_multiline_type_metrics(tmp_image, text)
  (metrics.width < width)
end
```

And I have another function to transform the text to fit in the specified width by adding new lines

```
def fit_text(text, width)
  separator = ' '
  line = ''

  if not text_fit?(text, width) and text.include? separator
    i = 0
    text.split(separator).each do |word|
      if i == 0
        tmp_line = line + word
      else
        tmp_line = line + separator + word
      end

      if text_fit?(tmp_line, width)
        unless i == 0
          line += separator
        end
        line += word
      else
        unless i == 0
          line +=  '\n'
        end
        line += word
      end
      i += 1
    end
    text = line
  end
  text
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This work as expected and is a huge timesaver to not have to re-implement.

Comment:  you're a saint among men

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
phrase = "my super long text that needs to be auto line breaked and cropped"
background = Magick::Image.read('my_bg_img.jpg').first
image = Magick::Image.read("caption:#{phrase}") do
  self.size = '800x600' #Text box size
  self.background_color = 'none' #transparent
  self.pointsize = 22 # font size
  self.font = 'Helvetica' #font family
  self.fill = 'gray' #font color
  self.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity #Text orientation
end.first
background.composite!(image, Magick::NorthEastGravity, 20, 40, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
background.format = "jpeg"
return background.to_blob
```

Comment: It works amazing! much cleaner. Be aware that instead of "my_text", you should use "phrase", in the third line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help someone, refactored logic from [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26182303/7121891)(without real drawing):

```rb
class RMagickTextWrapper
  SEPARATOR = ' '.freeze

  def initialize(font_size, path_to_font_file = nil)
    @drawing = Magick::Draw.new
    @drawing.pointsize = font_size
    @drawing.font = path_to_font_file if path_to_font_file
  end

  def text_with_line_breaks(text, width_of_bounding_box)
    return text if text_fit?(text, width_of_bounding_box) || text.exclude?(SEPARATOR)

    text.split(SEPARATOR).each_with_object('').with_index do |(word, line), index|
      tmp_line = "#{line}#{SEPARATOR}#{word}"

      line.concat(text_fit?(tmp_line, width_of_bounding_box) ? SEPARATOR : '\n') if index != 0
      line.concat(word)
    end
  end

  private

  def text_fit?(text, width)
    @drawing.get_multiline_type_metrics(text).width < width
  end
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Found some code [here](http://viseztrance.com/2011/03/texts-over-multiple-lines-with-rmagick.html) that does the trick :)