# MiniMagick wrap text on image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, imagemagick, minimagick

On Rails 5.2.1, I am attempting to use MiniMagick to write text on an image. The problem is, it overflows beyond the bounds of the image's width for long texts.

I have attempted to use `draw`, `label`, `annotation` and `caption` methods from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption) but none give me the right result. `caption` does not even add the text to the image.

This is my code:

```
      temp_img = MiniMagick::Image.open(url_for(@post.image))
      img_width = temp_img[:width]

      temp_img.combine_options do |c|
        c.gravity 'North'
        c.draw "text 0, 0 '#{top_txt}'"
        #c.annotate '0,0', "'#{top_txt}'" (same result)
        #c.caption "'#{top_txt}'" (same result)
        #c.label "'#{top_txt}'" (same result)
        c.gravity 'South'
        c.draw "text 0, 0 '#{bot_txt}'"
        #c.annotate '0,0', "'#{bot_txt}'" (same result)
        #c.caption "'#{bot_txt}'" (same result)
        #c.label "'#{bot_txt}'" (same result)
        c.stroke('#000000')
        c.strokewidth 1
        c.fill('#FFFFFF')
        c.size "#{img_width}x"
        c.pointsize '40'
        c.font "#{Rails.root.join('public', 'font',
        'Franklin_Gothic_Heavy_Regular.ttf')}"
      end
```

This is my result:
[image]
The closest I have seen to a solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26182303/3491653) but is too messy.

Could there be a better way?

Comment: I ended up using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26182303/3491653) answer as it gave me the best/desired behavior

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I do not know Minimagick. But in ImageMagick command line there is label: that automatically fits text to some dimension such as the image width. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label. If MiniMagick does not support that directly, then perhaps you could use Ruby/Rmagick commands. See https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick (methods section), assuming RMagick supports a label: like method. Note that with label: and caption: you have to create a new image with with your text on a transparent background and then composite it over your original image.

Here is an example:

Input:

[image]

```
convert image.png \( -size 639x -background none -font Arial -fill black label:"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" \) -gravity center -compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Convert with MiniMagick and the syntax is a little tricky because there isn't many examples with Ruby for it.

```
caption_string = "caption: #{top_txt}"

MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |img|
  img.gravity 'north'
  img.stroke '#000000'
  img.strokewidth 1
  img.fill '#FFFFFF'
  img.size "#{img_width}x"
  img.pointsize '40' #don't add this if you want it to adjust according to size
  img.font "#{Rails.root.join('public', 'font',
    'Franklin_Gothic_Heavy_Regular.ttf')}"
  img << caption_string
  img << url_for(@post.image)
end
```